# Magento: Is it possible to get the direct link from checkout's shipping step?

Tags: php, magento

Right now i am using Mangeto 1.9.

I want to get an iframe from the shipping step of the checkout process and display it on other page.

Here is how my checkout link looks like right now:

http://www.mymagento.com/checkout/onepage/

And there is no change in this link while you go thrue all the steps in the check out?

My question is how i can take the direct link from the shipping step for example and is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Well behind the scenes there's javascript that controls the cart and you have to fill out the prior steps to get there,however, what is your goal?   There maybe a completely different approach that may satisfy your needs.